# Как узнать тип стороннего приложения C#?

Tags: c#

Как узнать тип стороннего приложения на C# - Консольное приложения или Windows Forms? Полез в Reflection - ничего не нашёл.

**UPD:**

Спасибо @PavelMayorov за подсказку, решение получилось таким:

```
using (Stream Stream = new FileStream(@"путь к файлу",FileMode.Open))
{
    using (BinaryReader BReader = new BinaryReader(Stream))
    {
        Stream.Position = 0x3C;
        uint peHeader = BReader.ReadUInt32();
        Stream.Position = peHeader+0x5C;
        ushort machine = BReader.ReadUInt16();
        Console.WriteLine(machine);
    }
}
```

Comment: стороннее приложение только в скомпилированном виде?

Comment: Да. Есть файл, например, application.exe. Мне надо узнать какого он типа, будь то exe/winexe..

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow. Лучше опубликовать ответ на свой собственный вопрос, если другие ответы не устраивают.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По смещению 0x3C от начала файла записано смещение заголовка PE (4 байта). Относительно начала PE заголовка по смещению 0x5C записан код подсистемы (2 байта). Если там 2 - это графическое приложение. Если 3 - консольное. Если что-то другое - это вообще не приложение win32.

Подробности можно узнать здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#windows_subsystem

Comment: Конкретно по субсистемам больше тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680339%28v=vs.85%29.aspx и таки Native Subsystem - виндовое приложение типа "драйвер".

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну не обязательно драйвер. Может быть просто нативное приложение, вроде чекдиска. Или, скажем, `winlogon.exe` - он же тоже нативный, но не драйвер. В любом случае, приложением win32 нативное приложение не является.

Comment: Спасибо, помог! Вот решение, может кому надо:
`using (Stream Stream = new FileStream(@"путь к файлу",FileMode.Open))
{
using (BinaryReader BReader = new BinaryReader(Stream))
{
Stream.Position = 0x3C;
uint peHeader = BReader.ReadUInt32();
Stream.Position = peHeader+0x5C;
ushort machine = BReader.ReadUInt16();
Console.WriteLine(machine);
}
}`

Comment: @PavelMayorov Win7, winlogon.exe имеет GUI-подсистему. WinXP - аналогично.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов хм, но он же загружается до запуска этой подсистемы...

Comment: @PavelMayorov но факт остается фактом: GUI (2) на двух разных системах. И API он дергает вполне себе обычные.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать функцию [SHGetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) с параметром SHGFI_EXETYPE:

```
public const uint SHGFI_EXETYPE = 0x000002000;

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, IntPtr psfi, 
        uint cbFileInfo, uint uFlags);

public static void PrintExeType(string file)
{            
        int res = SHGetFileInfo(file, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 0, SHGFI_EXETYPE);

        int lowWord = res & 0xffff;
        int hiWord = res >> 16;

        if (res != 0)
        {
            if (hiWord == 0x0000 && lowWord == 0x5a4d /*MZ*/) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DOS application");
            }
            else if (hiWord == 0x0000 && lowWord == 0x4550 /*PE*/)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Console application");
            }
            else if ((hiWord != 0x0000) && (lowWord == 0x454E/*NE*/ || lowWord == 0x4550 /*PE*/))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("GUI application");
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("Unknown");
        }
        else MessageBox.Show("Not executable");            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Не скажу что способ хороший, но вдруг

```
    private void TestIsWindowExe()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(IsWindowExe("notepad.exe", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(IsWindowExe("cmd.exe", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка исполняемого файла, является ли он оконным
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exepath">путь к исполняемому файлу</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">время ожидания загрузки программы</param>
    /// <returns>Является ли оконным</returns>
    private bool IsWindowExe(string exepath, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = exepath;            
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        bool iswindow;
        try
        {               
            if (process.WaitForInputIdle(Convert.ToInt32(timeout.TotalMilliseconds)))
               iswindow = true;
            else
               throw new TimeoutException("Превышен таймаут ожидания загрузки процесса");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            iswindow = false;
        }
        process.Kill();
        return iswindow;
    }
```

Comment: Напомнило сложение дат через `Thread.Sleep` :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ссылку не дадите? что-то не гуглится